# Peut-on remplacer « par cela », construction qui utilise un pronom emphatique, par « par elles » ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, démonstratifs

Cette question est issue de *Advanced French Grammar* (p. 153) de V. Mazet :

> Prepositions such as selon, malgré, pour, and par can`t be left at the end of the sentence, but they mustn't be removed either. The only option here is to use ça. In this case, ça serves the function of a "neutral stress pronoun," heard in spoken language. It can replace a noun object or an infinitive clause object.

Exemple de Guillaume Louis Julien Carré ([Source](http://books.google.com/books?id=_CJEAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA114&dq=%22effectue+par+cela%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=8zqtUvjsM-uNiAfrxIDQCw&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22effectue%20par%20cela%22&f=false)) :

> Dans l'espèce, c'était à Bruxelles que les ventes avaient été arrêtées, les marchandises livrées; c'est encore dans cette ville que le paiement aurait dû être effectué **par cela**  ***seul que*** la délivrance s'y était faite.

Je comprends que *par cela* signifie ici « par les marchandises livrées ». Alors, peut-on écrire « par elles » (les marchandises livrées) ?

---

Supplément daté le 19 décembre 2013 :

Prière d'éclaricir et expliciter la structure ***seul que*** ? Équivaut-elle à **le seul fait que** (d'après la réponse de l'utilisateur un francophone) ? Peut-être que voici la source de mon embarras.

Answer (score 3):

L'antécédent de cela est « la délivrance s'y était faite » (on aurait pu écrire aussi « par le seul fait que la délivrance s'y était faite »).  On ne peut utiliser « elle » ou « lui » dans ce genre de structure que pour des personnes (« la livraison a été faite par lui qui était déjà venu hier ») et souvent « celle » ou « celui » sera préférable (à un tel point que je ne trouve pas d'exemple où ce n'est pas le cas).

Comment: Je vous suis reconnaissant et ai plussoyé. SVP, pourriez-vous répondre dans votre réponse à mon supplément ci-devant dans mon OP ?

Comment: @LePressentiment: OP signifie Original Poster, « mon OP » ne veut rien dire. Par ailleurs, merci d'éviter les requêtes directes adressées à un utilisateur particulier. Les utilisateurs répondront s'ils en ont le temps et l'envie ; a priori ils n'apprécient pas forcément être directement sollicités.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: Merci de vos conseils. J'ai adapté OP pour abréger "Original Post." Est-ce que je devrais réécrire mon commentaire ci-devant ? Je ne suis pas sûr si ce soit l'objet de votre commentaire.